# String Constant not working in SuppressWarnings annotation

Tags: java, annotations, pmd

I have couple of junit tests which don't have any `assert` statements. Junit just passes or

expects `exception`. But because of this PMD complains that the tests should include `assert`

or verify `PMD.JUnitTestsShouldIncludeAssertOrVerify`.

So I defined a static final string constant because there are many methods.

```
private static final String PMD_WARNING = "PMD.JUnitTestsShouldIncludeAssertOrVerify";

@SuppressWarnings(PMD_WARNING)
public void test...{
}
```

But this does not seem to be working. It's compiling fine but `PMD` check is not recognizing the `SuppressWarnings` annotation anymore and failing. If I directly include the literal string as an argument to the `SuppressWarnings` annotation instead of using the constant, it works fine.

Is there any reason why it's not working?

Comment: @SurpressWarning is a desgin-time Statement. It cannot reference values generated during compile-time

Comment: Compiles fine here, once you use `SuppressWarnings` and not `SupressWarnings`.

Comment: @JBNizet, That was a typo. I am using `SuppressWarnings` - updated

Comment: That's the problem. There are 2 p's in `SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: And with *not working*, I meant `PMD` is complaining. It's compiling fine.

Comment: @NathanHughes, Updated. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the question then. Must be a strange PMD bug. Using SuppressWarnings(UNCHECKED) where UNCHECKED is a constant containing "unchecked" works fine for removing unchecked compiler warnings.

Comment: probably this explains a bit http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188192/thread/448e3bf1

Answer (score 1):

All the annotations including @SupressWarnings will be evaluated at compile time.

but static final value is evaluated the first time this class is loaded.

so at compile time during the evaluation time of @SupressWarnings , your constant string is not yet loaded and available.

Comment: So does compiler see something like ```@SupressWarnings("")```?